# azure deploy multiple site's instance on demand

Tags: c#, azure, web

I have a website called www.Request.com, when users access this site they will be able to request the creation of a new instance of another website that is already deployed in AZURE with the name www.MyTechnicalApp.com
for example when I access to www.Request.com I will request the creation of MyTechnicalApp for my company called "MyCompany", it's supposed that there is a script that will be executed by request.com website to create automatically www.MyCompany.MyTechnicalApp.com website.
would you please let me know how could I do that?

Comment: There's probably some Azure SDKs you can worth with to achieve that. Unfortunately, it's too broad a question for this website.

Comment: Look into ARM templates if you want to deploy an environment automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this link to get the credentials Authentication in Azure Management Libraries for Java.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java/blob/master/AUTH.md

The below link helped me to find the answer.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var resourceGroupName = "your ressource group name";
            var subId = "64da6c..-.......................88d";
            var appId = "eafeb071-3a70-40f6-9e7c-fb96a6c4eabc";
            var appSecret = "YNlNU...........................=";
            var tenantId = "c5935337-......................19";
            var environment = AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud;
            var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(appId, appSecret, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
            var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
         .Configure()
         .Authenticate(credentials)
         .WithSubscription(subId);

            azure.AppServices.WebApps.Inner.CreateOrUpdateHostNameBindingWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceGroupName, "WebSiteName", "SubDomainName",
              new HostNameBindingInner(
                        azureResourceType: AzureResourceType.Website,
                        hostNameType: HostNameType.Verified,
                        customHostNameDnsRecordType: CustomHostNameDnsRecordType.CName)).Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://socialhook.me/sh/programming/questions/36828116/how+to+set+ssl+bindings+on+azure+web+apps+via+management+rest+api

Comment: You can use this video if you want to add an SSL certificate https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AuMj31MEy5E

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, to create a web app on Azure automatically, there are two ways to achieve this.

**One:** using "Windows Azure Management Libraries", this SDK is a wrapper around "Azure Service Management" API.

First, we need to do authentication with ASM API and we can refer to: [Windows Azure Management Librairies : Introduction et authentification](https://blogs.infinitesquare.com/posts/cloud/windows-azure-management-librairies-introduction-et-authentification#.VzRHyfmLQ2x), then we will be able to create a website with something like this:

```
using (var AwsManagement = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites.WebSiteManagementClient(azureCredentials))
{

     WebSiteCreateParameters parameters = new WebSiteCreateParameters()
     {
          Name = "myAws",
          // this Service Plan must be created before
          ServerFarm = "myServiceplan",
      };

      await AwsManagement.WebSites.CreateAsync("myWebSpace", parameters, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

**Two:** We can create a web site by using a POST request that includes the name of the web site and other information in the request body. We can check the code example for [azure-sdk-for-net](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/src/ServiceManagement/WebSite/WebSiteManagement/Generated/WebSiteOperations.cs#LC1007)